# UML class diagram for a specified parking guidance system?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I made this class diagram based on specification of a Parking Guidance System. This is the first time for me to draw UML Class Diagram, so can you tell me if it's ok?

[image]

Here the specifications on which I had to base my model.

1. Customer Module

   a. Enables customer to print ticket for entry station with entry id, plate 
    number, transaction date

   b. Enables customer to pay in exit station for parking hours with entry id.
2. Operator in Entry Station

   a. Enables operator to monitor free spots in Parking

   b. Enables operator to advise customer with free spot.
3. Operator in Exit Station

   a. Enter ticket id to calculate total parking hours
4. Admin Module

   a. Enables admin to add spots in parking.

   b. Enables admin to view total spots in parking.

   c. Enables admin to add / update / delete users with different roles

   d. Enables admin to view shifts report with payment

   e. Enables admin to view parked cars report

Comment: Simple answer: no. You are using connectors at random. Learn what they mean first. Once you got that, start another attempt.

Comment: Probably you should ask on Stack Exchange which seems a better fit for such design oriented questions. I voted to close this as too broad, simply because there is no _specific_ question here.